# Symfony2 : Image Modification with doctrine lifcycle functions

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Hellow Everybody

i'm new in symfony2 world, i'm working on a e-commerce project and i need to modifiy the image of a product, i use doctrine life cycle functions to upload the image and liipimaginebundle to handle to thmbnails. my code is

Article.php

```
<?php

namespace StoreBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Image
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="image")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="StoreBundle\Repository\ImageRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Image
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at",type="datetime", nullable=true) 
     */
    private $updateAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\PostLoad()
     */
    public function postLoad()
    {
        $this->updateAt = new \DateTime();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=255, nullable=true) 
     */
    private $path;


    public $file;   

    public function getUploadRootDir()
    {
        return __dir__.'/../../../public_html/uploads';
    }

    public function getAbsolutePath()
    {
        return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->path;
    }

    public function getAssetPath()
    {
        return 'uploads/'.$this->path;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate() 
     */
    public function preUpload()
    {
        $this->tempFile = $this->getAbsolutePath();
        $this->oldFile = $this->getPath();
        $this->updateAt = new \DateTime();

        if (null !== $this->file)
            $this->path = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(),true)).'.'.$this->file->guessExtension();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostPersist()
     * @ORM\PostUpdate() 
     */
    public function upload()
    {
        if (null !== $this->file) {
            $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(),$this->path);
            unset($this->file);

            if ($this->oldFile != null) unlink($this->tempFile);
        }
    }


    /**
     * @ORM\PreRemove() 
     */
    public function preRemoveUpload()
    {
        $this->tempFile = $this->getAbsolutePath();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostRemove() 
     */
    public function removeUpload()
    {
        if (file_exists($this->tempFile)) unlink($this->tempFile);
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set updateAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updateAt
     * @return Image
     */
    public function setUpdateAt($updateAt)
    {
        $this->updateAt = $updateAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updateAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getUpdateAt()
    {
        return $this->updateAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set path
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @return Image
     */
    public function setPath($path)
    {
        $this->path = $path;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get path
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPath()
    {
        return $this->path;
    }

}
```

ArticleImageType.php

```
<?php

namespace StoreBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

use StoreBundle\Form\ImageType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;

class ArticleImageType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('image', new ImageType())
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'StoreBundle\Entity\Article'
        ));
    }
}
```

And in my controller i put :

```
public function imageEditAction(Request $request, Article $article)
    {
        $editForm = $this->createForm('StoreBundle\Form\ArticleImageType', $article);
        $editForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($article);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_article_show', array('id' => $article->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render('AdminBundle:article:imageEdit.html.twig', array(
            'article' => $article,
            'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

when i try modifying the image. is doesn't modified, and the old image is appears in the article. i need your help please and thanks in advance